# Что значит, что параметры должны быть URL-encoded? GET запрос

Tags: python, requests

В документации по API написано, что параметры при передаче в запрос должны быть ***"URL-encoded"***
Что это значит?
Я делаю запрос с параметрами, которые должны быть судя по документации ***"URL-encoded"***.

```py
params = {'tag': value, 'tag2': value2}
response = requests.get(url, params = params)
```

В результате получаю

> requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Полагаю, что ошибка именно из-за этих параметров.

Для сведения `tag` имеет вид числа в строке, типа `"12345"`
а параметр `tag2` имеет виде даты в строке типа `"2023-01-02 Tue 22:00"`

Comment: "Полагаю, что ошибка именно из-за этих параметров." - возможно, но ошибка скорее всего возникает, когда вы берете `response.json()`, а не в приведенном примере кода. Сначала я бы посмотрел, что находится в `response.text` (текст ошибки, вероятно), а потом уже делал выводы из-за чего она возникла. Ну еще код статуса ответа не помешало бы посмотреть. Может там вообще какой-нибудь 404, а вы просто по неправильному url обращаетесь.

Comment: По поводу url-encoded - по идее requests сам url параметры кодирует. P.S. и действительно, вот они параметры вполне себе url-encoded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Sot.png Так что проблема совсем не в этом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ, конечно, легко гуглится, но можно и тут немного тему раскрыть.

Вот вам пример ссылки, которая кодирована и действительна (ссылка на эту страницу)

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1534853/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-url-encoded-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81
```

То есть некоторые символы заменены. Конкретно в данном случае русские буквы.

Вы упоминаете, что используется формат даты `"2023-01-02 Tue 22:00"`, которая содержит как минимум пробелы, что является не допустимым при использовании в ссылке.

Что делать и как проверить. Можно воспользоваться тем же `requests`, хотя `urllib` тоже может в этом помочь

```py
import requests

value2 = "2023-01-02 Tue 22:00"
print(requests.utils.quote(value2))
```

Вывод будет таким

```
2023-01-02%20Tue%2022%3A00
```

Как было указано в комментариях к вопросу, модуль-`requests` сам собирает и кодирует ссылку, как этого требуется и ничего дополнительного делать не надо.

Здесь нужно поработать с ответом от запроса.

Посмотреть ссылку после получения ответа на запрос

```py
print(response.url)
```

Посмотреть ответ, как он есть

```py
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Да, я уже нагуглил и все заработало.